# Найти среднее время между срабатыванием событий

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

В дазу данных(PostgreSQL) записывается время события.

- 2023-10-19 00:24:06.625
- 2023-10-19 00:24:08.661
- 2023-10-19 00:24:13.753
- ...

Как написать запрос, чтобы получить среднее время(секунды/миллисекунды) между событиями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я создал следующую таблицу и данные:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE event_log (
    event_time timestamp
);

INSERT INTO event_log (event_time) VALUES
    ('2023-10-19 00:24:06.625'),
    ('2023-10-19 00:24:08.661'),
    ('2023-10-19 00:24:13.753'),
    ('2023-10-19 00:24:20.321'),
    ('2023-10-19 00:24:25.999'),
    ('2023-10-19 00:24:30.475'),
    ('2023-10-19 00:24:32.890'),
    ('2023-10-19 00:24:40.150');
```

Сначала посчитаем разницу между текущим событием и предыдущим событием, можно использовать `lag` с сортировкой по времени (для хронологического порядка).

```
SELECT
   event_time - lag(event_time) OVER (ORDER BY event_time) AS time_interval
FROM event_log
```

Затем, используя `AVG`, вычислим среднее значение временных интервалов.

```
SELECT AVG(time_interval) AS average_time
FROM (
    SELECT
        event_time - lag(event_time) OVER (ORDER BY event_time) AS time_interval
    FROM event_log
) subquery;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ge0SfipG)